# Return (T)Request[key];

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this existing code which works very well.

```
public static T SessionGet<T>(string key)
{
    if (Session[key] == null)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)Session[key];
}
```

I wanted to make a version that works for Request. I realise that Request is string based. So how can I change the code so that error, as in the comment below,  does not occur without having to place a large switch based on typeof(T).

```
return (T)Request[key]; // Cannot cast expression of type 'string' to type '(T)'
```

Here is the function....

```
public static T RequestGet<T>(string key)
{
    if (Request[key] == null)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)Request[key];
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* use the `Convert.ChangeType` method to accomplish this, but you're relying on the inputs to be *correct*, otherwise you'll get an exception. `Request` deals with user supplied data, so this assumption is *extremely* risky. This isn't the same as what you're doing with `Session`, as you control what goes into `Session`. That's not the case with `Request`.

```
public static T RequestGet<T>(string key)
{
    if (Request[key] == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Request[key], typeof(T));
        // return (T)Request[key];
    }
}
```

In your shoes, I might want to rely on safer methods of getting, validating, and parsing user inputs so that the application doesn't become a mess of exception handling or error screens.

Comment: Fantastic! ChangeType is new to me.